# How to make efficient list from particular object in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Hey I have list of object in which I want to combine `title` **property** value into list of object. I did this successfully without any problem. My main questions is there any better approach to do in kotlin which helps in efficient, better memory management and everything when `eventList` is bigger in size.

CombineList.kt

```
fun main() {
    val newList = mutableListOf<String>()
    val eventList = createData()
    eventList.forEachIndexed { _, event ->
        val title = event.title
        if (!title.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            newList.add(title)
        }
    }
    println(newList)
}

data class Event(val title: String? = null, val status: String? = null)

fun createData() = listOf(
    Event("text 1", "abc"),
    Event("text 2", "abc"),
    Event("text 3", "abc"),
    Event("text 4", "abc"),
    Event("", "abc"),
    Event(null, "abc")
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a new list and iteratively add each element in a `forEach`, you can use map which yields a new list with all the results of mapping the given function to each element:

```
val newList = eventList.map { it.title }.filterNot { it.isNullOrEmpty() }
```

The `filterNot` works in a similar way, giving you a list of all elements in a list, that do *not* fulfill a given predicate.

An overview of common operations for collections [can be found here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-operations.html#common-operations).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a list of all titles with *map* and then filter out null and empty values it might be better to create the list with *mapNotNull* (and to convert empty strings to null in its lambda):

```
val newList = createData().mapNotNull { it.title?.ifEmpty { null } }
```